# How to programmatically read Mac .textClipping files?

Tags: cocoa, finder

Those files are created whenever you drag a text selection to the Finder. The file size is always `0 bytes`. Apparently the data is stored in a resource fork.

I tried reading the resource fork[1], but get error code `-39` (end of file).

Here some more details about the file:

```
$>xattr  test.textClipping 
com.apple.FinderInfo
com.apple.ResourceFork
```

[1] http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UsingResourceForks

Comment: Warning: macOS Sierra and High Sierra's Finder's "Compress" destroys the resource fork on .textClipping files when compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up *FSOpenFork* and *FSReadFork*.
(Apple has a code sample called [AudioCDSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioCDSample/Listings/AudioCDSample_c.html)).

There'a also a command line tool that can read those files (**/usr/bin/DeRez**), you may want to look at it under GDB, but from what I've seen it uses deprecated APIs (i.e. *FSRead* in place of *FSReadFork*).

Comment: The code sample is no longer available at that link, but it is available as [a stuffit archive at this mirror](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/samplecode/AudioCDSample/AudioCDSample.html).

Answer (score 5):

A textClipping file is an old fashioned resource fork file. You'll want to open it using `FSOpenResourceFile`, and then use `Get1Resource` to read the resources out of the file.  The file might contain a few different resources types for the text: 'RTF ' (rich text), 'utxt' (UTF-8), 'utf8' (UTF-8), or 'TEXT' (ASCII) type resources, all with id 256.  Once you read the resource, extract the data from the Handle and do with it what you want.

Comment: How would I access the different data types (I've managed to read the data)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in macOS 10.12 Sierra, a .textClipping file is now a property list.

The root dictionary has the key "UTI-Data". Within that, the keys: com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-text, public.utf16-plain-text, and public.utf8-plain-text hold a couple different representations of the data.

Here's an example that will read from a path:

```
NSString *path = @"/path/to/file.textClipping";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:0 format:nil error:&error];
NSString *text;

if (plist && error == nil) {
  NSDictionary *utiData = [plist objectForKey:@"UTI-Data"];
  text = [utiData objectForKey:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];
}
```

Comment: You can convert to xml with '$ plutil --convert xml1 file.textClipping'.  Do a man plutil, and do a plutil -help for additional info.  It overwrites the original unless you use -o filename.  (this is in mojave 10.14)